# Dynamic allocated row height of css grid gets stretched with growing content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728855/flex-container-vertical-overflowing-parent-div/51729058?noredirect=1#comment90442366_51729058) I´m struggling with using CSS grid to create a layout with fixed header and footer containing an middle row, which should use the remaining space of the `.static` or `.dynamic` dynamic container. So in this case, both oth them should have a complete `height` of 200px. Subtracting the 40px (2x 20px for header + footer) the remaining space for the content should be 160px. As you can see at the example, the red reference div on the left is clearly smaller than the whole "sandwich" of div containers. The `.dynamic` div element is to large and will stretch the whole div container. **I want to prohibit this!**

Here are a few additional conditions I have to fullfill:

1. The whole layout should be dynamic, so the `.wrapper` div later wont have a static height, but will fill 100% of the given height. therefore only`dynamic` will be used, since this also uses 100% of the height. The showcase with `.static` is just there to show that it doesn´t even work with fixed heights.
2. Neither static nor dynamic should work with overflow to create scrollbars or hidden overflowing content. It should just restrict the dynamic area between `.header` and `.footer` to an height.
3. The containing `.content` container will expand itself to 100% width and should be treatet as a kind of blackbox: every component should be able to be inserted here. The content will always use 100% of the height and should not strech the ambient parent divs. The content will contain an scrollbar on its own, if the height of the content will be heigher than the dynamically allocated space of the `.dynamic` container

***How am I able to solve this issue with the given description?***

Please see the provided example and feel free to adapt it as you need to!

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.measurement {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.static,
.dynamic {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20px 1fr 20px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.static {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  /*should NOT have an overflow/scrollbar but fit to the remaining space*/
}

.dynamic {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /*should NOT have an overflow/scrollbar but fit to the remaining space*/
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Blackbox like content, always expands to 100% width and height */
  /* could contain content that is larger than the dynamic-height div and will get scrollbar then */
}

.fixed-height {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="measurement"></div>
  <div class="static">
    <div class="fixed-height">TOP</div>
    <div class="dynamic-height">
      <div class="content">
        TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-height">BOTTOM</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dynamic">
    <div class="fixed-height">TOP</div>
    <div class="dynamic-height">
      <div class="content">
        TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-height">BOTTOM</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
As you can see in the image below, the TEST and BOTTOM text is beyond the blue borders. I´m not about the few pixels difference between the borders and the red reference but I'm concerned about the overflow over the bottom border.

[image]

This is the expected behaviour: there should be a scrollbar inside the content area, no overflow and no scrollbar inside dynamic div

[image]

Comment: The .static and the .dynamic height are actually 200px and the .measurement have the same height, but you are forgetting that you have these props on .static and .dynamic class: border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 1px;

Comment: @bruce182 Yeah sure, but as you can see at the example, the TEST and BOTTOM text is outside the blue border. I´ll attatch an image to prevent cross browser issues

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, my first comment was for assure that you didn't forget that you need to add the pixels of these props too to you measurement class.

Comment: Could you post an image with the expeted result please?

Comment: Just add `overflow: auto` to `.dynamic-height` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5ymuxae1/2/) | [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge the `div.content` with the `div.dynamic-height` and set the `max-height: 100%` property to your `.dynamic-height` class.

`.content` doesn't need an height, it's setted by the definition of the grid row.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.measurement {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.static,
.dynamic {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20px 1fr 20px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.static {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  /*should NOT have an overflow/scrollbar but fit to the remaining space*/
}

.dynamic {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /*should NOT have an overflow/scrollbar but fit to the remaining space*/
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Blackbox like content, always expands to 100% width and height */
  /* could contain content that is larger than the dynamic-height div and will get scrollbar then */
}

.fixed-height {
  background-color: green;
}
.dynamic-height {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="measurement"></div>
  <div class="static">
    <div class="fixed-height">TOP</div>
    <div class="dynamic-height content">
        TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-height">BOTTOM</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dynamic">
    <div class="fixed-height">TOP</div>
    <div class="content dynamic-height">
        TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-height">BOTTOM</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach doesn´t work, the snippet still has the same result with overflowing issues. That´s intresting: it IS working for firefox but not for chrome

Comment: @JohnDizzle "The content will contain an scrollbar on its own, if the height of the content will be heigher than the dynamically allocated space of the .dynamic container"